# Code not synced throwing Index was out of bounds array?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Before you mark this question as a duplicate, here is the tricky part I don't understand. This error is sporadic, I believe the code is correct and it's always working and I'm handling the possible mistakes with an if else condition inside the Reader part. Here is the code:

```
public static Tuple<int, string> GetIDAndString(string term)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = GetConnection())
        using (cmd = new SqlCommand())
        using (myReader)
        {
            int ID = 0;
            string status = string.Empty;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT t.TableID, t.Status
                                FROM Table t WITH (NOLOCK) /* I know NOLOCK is not causing the mistake as far as I know */
                                WHERE t.Term = @term";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term);

            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                ID = myReader.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : myReader.GetInt32(0);
                status = myReader.IsDBNull(1) ? string.Empty : myReader.GetString(1).Trim();
            }

            myReader.Close();

            return new Tuple<int, string>(ID, status);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I know I should be using a class instead of a Tuple, but I can't change that existing code and as you can see. So the main problem is that in the production server there was a `Index out of bounds array exception` in that method but I can't identify what's the problem.

Even if the term is not found in the query, the myReader will not enter and I'll return the ID = 0, status = string.Empty. Sometimes when I'm debugging code and working on the `develpment server`, my code starts to crash everywhere, showing me exceptions where is tested code and I have to reopen the solution to avoid that (I haven't found a solution to that, not even cleaning the solution).

So I hope someone have experience with something like that in a `production server`. I don't have specifications to the production server so I don't know anything about the server.

Comment: Create new data reader don't share it ! This could bring you problems !

Comment: Do agree with previous comment, either create new instance or synchronize access to it.

Comment: @mybirthname, I'm new to programming, you said not to share the dataReader. You mean not using a class where I declared a protected static SqlDataReader and then using it in a using block?

Comment: Post the full exception.

Comment: @JorgeF check my answer what I mean don't define the SqlReader as static global field. If someone is using this field it will become mess. Imagine you have another method in which someone is reading something else. The static fields are shared between all the users on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't need the `try/catch` block, you don't do anything with it. After that don't share `SqlDataReader` in the class, this could bring problems and probably the problem comes from this. You are overwriting the value of `ID` and `Status` all the time in your while. Probably a good idea will be to call `Top 1` on your query and order it by with correct field. Also there is no need to `Dispose()` the `SqlCommand`, the Constructor of `SqlCommand` is calling `SupressFinalization()`.

Why this problem can happen: Imagine your query returns 1000 records with `TableID` and `Status` column and you are entering the while loop. In this moment some other user is going in your application and executing another method which overwrites the `SqlDataReader` and return 5 records with only one column. On the next iteration of you while loop you will receive your exception. Because of that you should never define your Readers as `static` for the whole class. Static variables are shared between all of application users.

```
public static Tuple<int, string> GetIDAndString(string term)
{
    int ID = 0;
    string status = string.Empty;

    using (SqlConnection con = GetConnection())
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT t.TableID, t.Status
                            FROM Table t WITH (NOLOCK) /* I know NOLOCK is not causing the mistake as far as I know */
                            WHERE t.Term = @term";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term);


        using(SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                 ID = myReader.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : myReader.GetInt32(0);
                 status = myReader.IsDBNull(1) ? string.Empty : myReader.GetString(1).Trim();
            }

        }

    }

    return new Tuple<int, string>(ID, status);
}
```

Comment: Great explanation! I'll give you the correct answer because it's the same as the other, but with an example of my code with best practices. Only other thing hope you can clarify that for me. If I'm using `protected static SqlTransaction` in the `GetConnection()` method, should I make the changes like the SqlReader inside the class? Or just for the SqlReader? Thanks

Comment: @JorgeF yes don't use static transaction. check msdn article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna make those changes

Comment: @JorgeF note, that his still shares cmd. Must be fixed as well.

Comment: @usr Thanks for mentioning it I forget to define it when remove it from the using block.

Answer (score 0):

this probably happens when you do `ID = myReader.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : myReader.GetInt32(0);` or `status = myReader.IsDBNull(1) ? string.Empty : myReader.GetString(1).Trim();` because the result set does not conform to your expectations. You should add logging of the reader's row before actually reading it, might help you pinpoint the issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is caused by the `myReader` field which I suppose is static. If you look at the `SqlDataReader` (I suppose that's the field's type) documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx, you'll find that instance methods are not thread safe, hence you must synchronize access to that field.

Answer (score 0):

`using (myReader)` captures the value that the reader had at that time and disposes that later. It does not remember the variable. This has to be so as you can see from this example: `using (Random() ? myReader : null)`. Clearly, the C# language will not reexecute that expression at dispose time. It runs it just once.

So you're disposing some old/other reader.

In case you are sharing objects between threads (maybe using static variables) this trivially is a race condition. Don't do that. Use locals. There is no need/advantage to use static variables here.